# Port Forwarding my apache server

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I am  trying port forwarding on my router, model: SAGEMCOM F@st3814 (couldn't find it in portforward.com).
I have followed the general instructions and in the screenshot below I am trying to set it up:

[image: Pic 1]

I have erased my external IP for privacy. 
Then when I click apply  I get an error message like the following. 
 [image]

When I change the start and end ports to 1 and 8081 resp. for both internal and external I do not get this error message. However, in this case,  the port forwarding doesn't work either (I used canyouseeme.org).

The Apache server at 192.168.1.15 is accessible through the LAN and it is on a linux machine without firewall.

Perhaps I am missing something trivial, perhaps someone has experience with this router model or its close relatives (it seems little less known than most brands). 
In any case I would help any explanations about what is going on and any advice. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just a hunch... But try just forwarding one port like 80 and see what happens.  Forwarding almost 9000 ports is likely the issue, and totally unnecessary, (and a security risk but that's beside the point).

Comment: My setup is fairly complicated and the end result is still only 9 ports forwarded. Total.  All machines.  I bet u can get by with 3 or less

Comment: I changed my settings to forward only one port. However my server is not accessible from outside network (WAN). The port is closed according to canyouseeme.org. Any suggestions?